# Why am I getting an OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError only on Windows?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https

I'm downloading files from a HTTPS website.  I've narrowed the problem down to this:

```
>> require 'open-uri'
>> open('https://www.gmail.com/') # just as an example
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:242:in `open_http'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
    from openuri_sandbox.rb:3
```

This code works just fine on Mac OS X or Linux, but it **just** started failing on Windows.  I've tested on a few Win XP installations and one Win 7 installation -- they all fail.  They're all running Ruby 1.8.6 patchlevel 287.  What's going on here?  We know we can turn off SSL verification and it works (or at least seems to), but that seems like a poor solution.

I'm interfacing with the website in question using Mechanize, so I'd like to be able to continue to use that.

**Update:** It looks like the problem with Mechanize might be specific to Windows 7, unlike I previously thought.  It worked just a couple of weeks ago, though.

**Update 2:** This is still happening on Windows (XP and 7), but not on Linux.  It's no longer a problem in the important script I needed to make work, though -- still not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appears it happens because ruby doesn't ship with certificates? http://betterlogic.com/roger/2011/08/github-jruby-ssl-woe/

Comment: I've run into enough other problems that had to do with Ruby's handling of certificates that this is my best guess for now.

Answer (score 0):

Could the difference be 32-bit vs 64-bit architecture?

Comment: It's possible.  I no longer have access to the machines in question, so I can't test that hypothesis.

Comment: It is an SSL and Ruby OpenSSL characteristic across platforms and architectures (see above answer).  Me thinks, folk don't _get_ security or encryption _per se_.  That makes for confusion, but also situations like this where the configuration on key middle-ware modules can be _problematic_.  (Just a _pov_)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeking the same solution myself.  I resolved this issue on the command line using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/) and the information to set-up a CA-bundle.  I'm still looking for a Ruby fix.

This is a common issue across on Linux, Windows, Windows, Mac, Ruby 1.8, Ruby 1.9 and JRuby from my testing/experiments.